# Find lines starting with one specific character and ending with another one

Tags: unix, grep, pattern-matching

I need to find a line in a file that starts with an **a** and the last word in the line ends with an **e**.

How can I do it with a tool like `grep`?

Comment: What is the question here? What the regex should be? You should consult a regex howto to learn that stuff...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just say this:

```
grep '^a.*e$' file
```

This means: look for those lines starting (`^`) with `a`, then 0 or more characters and finally and `e` at the end of the line (`$`).

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
and thisfinishes with e
foo
$ grep '^a.*e$' a
and thisfinishes with e
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer : use grep.

```
grep -E "^a.*e$" filename
```

the `^` indicates the beggining of the line
the `$` marks the end of the line
the `.*` means any character (the `.`) repeated from zero to any number of times (the `*`).
Many topics have already answered this questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800214/grep-for-beginning-and-end-of-line).
If you want to know more of searching, you could look more in depth into [REGEX](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html).

Comment: there is no need for `-E` here, simple grep behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -E '.*sam.*t' filename
```

here .* is used for any character that regex can find.
here "sam" is the word in my case.