# Output desired text only

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file as:

```
$ cat file
.
.
4h
5h
6h
7h
.
.
.
16h
17h
18h
.
.
```

I want to output only the lines that have '6h' and '7h' but using below awk it selects also '16h' and '17h' :(

awk '/6h/ || /7h/{print}' file

How can I make it select only '6h' and '7h' without the '16h' and '17h'.
AWK is not mandatory if any other command does the job more easly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4800246/171318

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With `grep` exact match operator:

```
grep -w "6h\|7h" file
```

From grep manual:

> -w, --word-regexp
>
> Select  only  those  lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

Comment: That would also match lines containing `123 7h`, for example

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
grep '^[67]h' file
```